# Unique ID based on the non-zero value and date R

Tags: r, dplyr

Trying to create a Unique ID for non-zero values in a column and based on the date column. Here is the sample of the dataset,

```
data<- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1656565620, 1656565680, 
1656565740, 1656565800, 1656565860, 1656565920, 1656565980, 1656566040, 
1656566100, 1656566160, 1656566220, 1656566280, 1656566340, 1656566400, 
1656566460, 1656566520, 1656566580, 1656566640, 1656566700, 1656566760, 
1656651960, 1656652020, 1656652080, 1656652140, 1656652200, 1656652260, 
1656652320, 1656652380, 1656652440, 1656652500, 1656652560, 1656652620, 
1656652680, 1656652740, 1656652800, 1656652860, 1656652920, 1656652980, 
1656653040, 1656653100, 1656653160, 1656653220, 1656653280, 1656653340, 
1656653400, 1656653460, 1656653520, 1656653580, 1656653640, 1656653700, 
1656653760, 1656653820, 1656653880, 1656653940, 1656654000, 1656654060, 
1656654120, 1656654180, 1656654240, 1656654300, 1656654360), tzone = "EST", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Date = structure(c(1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 
1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 
1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 
1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 1656561600, 1656648000, 
1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 
1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 
1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 
1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 
1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 
1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 
1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000, 1656648000), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Value = c(720, 1140, 1560, 1680, 1680, 1800, 1920, 
1920, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1920, 1920, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 840, 1080, 1500, 1620, 1680, 
1740, 1860, 1920, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 480, 
360, 1380)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -61L), groups = structure(list(Date = structure(c(1656561600, 
1656648000), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .rows = structure(list(
    1:20, 21:61), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

In the dataset, I would like to have a unique ID for each non-zero event and for each day, respectively. In specific, the ID should restart for each day.

I tried the following,

```
`cycleID <- as.integer(factor(cumsum(data$value==0)*NA^(data$value==0)))`
```

But this creates the continous ID irrespective of the date. I tried `group_by(Date)` in dplyr, but its not working.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: If the code you post works for a single day then `library(dplyr); data |> mutate(cycleID = as.integer(factor(cumsum(value==0)*NA^(value==0))), .by = Date)` should work just fine for multiple days. If not, then I would suggest modifying your example to include multiple days, as that seems a crucial part of the problem. To illustrate the problem we do not need 1-minute-resolution. I would think 2 days with 10 rows each would be plenty.

Comment: Another benefit of a small example is that you can easily show the desired result for the sample input so there is no confusion.

Comment: I would also recommend pasting ungrouped data into your question. If it needs to be grouped then one of the responses suggest that.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas, Thanks. I have modified the data based on your suggestion.

Comment: @GregorThomas, Yes! adding .by=Date, worked. Many thanks for your very quick response. Appreciate it

Comment: @LMc, thanks for highlighting the ungrouped data.

Comment: @LMc
Grouped data was the problem. Before I was trying,
df<- df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(cycleIDwwww = as.integer(factor(cumsum(Value==0)*NA^(Value==0))))
The above code was not working. After I ungrouped, the code just works fine. 
Thanks again